A step in a proof of Zorn's Lemma in Jech's Set Theory
The following is the first step of a proof of Zorn's Lemma in Jech's Set Theory:

Proof: We construct (using a choice function for nonempty subsets of $P$), a chain in $P$ that leads to a maximal element of $P$. We let, by induction,
$$
a_\alpha = \text{an element of } P \text{ such that } a_\alpha > a_\xi \text{ for every } \xi < \alpha \text{ if there is one.}
$$

Now, the choice function has the property $f(S) \in S$ for every subset $S$ of $P$. How exactly does this allow us to construct the $a_\alpha$?

Since every chain has an upper bound, if your chain has a proper upper bound, then the set of proper upper bounds is non-empty, and so we can use $f$ to choose from it.
If the set of proper upper bounds is in fact empty, then it could only happen if the upper bound of your chain is a maximal element (and is in the chain itself).
